# mailgun messages are queued but not sent

Tags: node.js, firebase, mailgun

I'm setting up a website with a node.js backend in firebase. One of the pages is a contact page where the user submits the form and its contents get sent to my email address.

I set everything up with mailgun, using the mailgun api.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));



function sendMsg(name, email, subject, message) {
    const mg = mailgun({
        apiKey: 'APIKEY',
        domain: 'sandboxrandomnumbers.mailgun.org'
    });

    const data = {
        from: `${name} <${email}>`,
        to: 'myemail',
        subject: subject,
        text: message
    };

    mg.messages().send(data, (err, body) => {
        console.log(body);
    })
}



app.post('/contact/success', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.name;
    let email = req.body.email;
    let subject = req.body.subject;
    let message = req.body.message;

    sendMsg(name, email, subject, message);

    res.redirect('/contact/success');
})



exports.website = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

What's happening is the messages are being queued but not sent (based on what is printed on the console). How do I make sure that the messages are sent immediately and not queued?

PS: I'm still a beginner so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the spam folder of your mail account. That's where those mails usually end up.


Also if you want to see the status of you mails, go to the "sending" menu in the side navbar.


There you can see the status of your mails like -   Name    Accepted, Delivered,    Bounced, Opened, Clicked, Complained, etc.


Check out this image -

[image]